# Apollo local state - how to query by id

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

If we have todos items like array of objects inside apollo client state cache - todos: [{name: 'First', id: 1}, {name: 'Second', id: 2}]. Is there is a way to query by id only the object that we need. Something like reselect - selector in redux. I want to subscribe by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apollo lets you do local state management using @client directives.
So you could create a query something like below to get a single TODO based on the id.

```
query getTodoById(id: ID!) @client {
  todo {
    name,
    id
  }
}

mutation setTodoById(id: ID!, todo: Todo!) @client {
  todo {
    name,
    id
  }
}
```

Now, you'll need to create a custom client resolver for the query above for Apollo to know where it should look up for the data in the cache. The custom resolver will take an argument called `getCachedKey` that generates the key of the object based on `typename` & `Id`. Apollo uses this generated Id from the custom resolver to look up data in the cache (the todos list).

Your custom client resolver should look something like this:

```
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      todo: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Todo', id: args.id })
    },
  };
```

Comment: I have todos: [{name: 'First', id: 1}, {name: 'Second', id: 2}] inside local state. I can get all todos with query - const query = `{ todos @client { name} }`. How I can take only First Todo like object. I don't want to take the whole array.

Comment: I see, you'll need to create a custom resolver that looks up your cached data to get you back the result for a single todo. See the edits for custom resolver code above.